# Sentence construction in reported speech

Tags: reported-speech, perfect-constructions

Is the sentence construction below correct for reported speech?

> A woman has complained to the police that her husband had mailed her
>   an instant triple talaq on a Rs 100 stamp paper after months of
>   harassment for dowry.

I am confused because the present prefect tense (has + past participle) and the past perfect tense (had + past participle) appear in the same sentence.

Answer (score 1):

The woman must have said to the police something like "my husband has mailed me...". That is the "speech" which is now to be "reported". So it must be "The woman said that her husband had...". As in, for example, the minutes of a meeting recording a decision: "The Chairman said that the board had decided...". His words at the meeting would have been "The board has decided...".
That is how reported speech works.
But there is something awkward about that sentence. Maybe it is just too long and complicated. "A woman has complained to the police about her husband. He had mailed her..."